# Reading the lines from command prompt?

Tags: c

I have question about C but my programming skills are not good as am still learning/studying.

Let me first explain my problem, out of pure curiosity and laziness i wanted to create some program in C that can auto ping some range of IP on my local network and give me what IP is alive.

Ok, so far without problem i managed to write few lines but am stuck on part where i need to read some lines from command prompt. After it execute this line, cmd start pinging the address it is provided.

```
system("ping 192.168.000.000")
```

So after it finishes this line can i read the info from cmd and use it to compare with other ping info?

Or there is some other way that i should start looking to solve this problem?

Comment: you could redirect the output to a file and read that

Comment: Use `popen()` to run `ping 192.168.000.000` and read its output as a `FILE*` stream.

Comment: There are many different ways to do this. One is redirect the output to file as already suggested. Another is to use [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen): "The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell". The caller can then read from the pipe to get the command output.

Comment: What do you mean by "*compare with other ping info?*" There may be a simple solution depending on what you want your comparison to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp = popen("ping 192.168.000.000", "r");
    //Read process output via fp and compare with other ping info
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The advantage of this method is you do not need a temporary file and you can read the output as it is produced, unbounded in size or time, which is very handy for `ping` as it does not stop under unix.  You can kill the process at any time with `pclose(fp);`.

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution to his problem.

Comment: The question is still open on what the OP means by "*compare with other ping info?*"

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the OP asks if *there is some other way that i should start looking to solve this problem*, comparing to other ping info is left as an exercise.

Comment: No critique on your answer, and what I actually meant, is the question on how to approach it IS answered, but the the question on what he does with his results after he gets that is still open. He mentions comparison with prior, where with `ping`, you are really getting only networking up/down info. In that case, rather than comparing between results, he could simply compare between the 2 possible responses from `ping`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sorry i didnt explane better, first i wanted to compare two ping time that i measure with clock() function ( ping time for alive address is much faster then the offline one but for some reason it's not always true 'atleast i thought so  :)' so that fails). Later i tried with "ping -a ip_address" that's where i stuck, "-a is parameter that resolve address to hostnames" so when you run "ping -a" right after pinging it shows hostname, so if  there is hostname on cmd its alive ip.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the output of your command to a text file and then read that file to get the output:

```
int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    system("ping 192.168.000.000 > output.txt");
    fp = fopen("output.txt", "r");
    //Read text file and do comparison
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ping` goes on forever on various Unix systems. Redirecting to a file and waiting for completion requires an extra argument such as `ping -c 10 192.168.0.0`.

Comment: Atm i have visual studio on win8.1 so first am gona do it here, ping on wins is not problem and i use only 1 parameter "-a" for resolving hostname. In CMD am gona look for hostname and it should be very fast as host name allways come as second string right after word "pinging hostname" if ip is offline there is no hostname "pinging ip_address". Does that sound ok?

Comment: After i write this my second goal will be to write it on ubuntu(this is the machine that mount my rpi-kodi thats working as local media center and yea rpi is the device that am pinging)

Answer (score 1):

You may want [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html), which allows you to read from the results of a command as from a file.